# Update column in postgresql using subquery

Tags: postgresql, group-by, sql-update, partition

I have a table name "table1" like this in postgresql db:

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
id TEXT,
class INT,
r1 DATE,
r2 DATE
);



INSERT INTO public.table1 (id, class, r1, r2)
VALUES ('x2', 2, '1/25/2015', '1/25/2015');

INSERT INTO public.table1 (id, class, r1, r2)
VALUES ('x2', 3, '6/28/2015', '1/25/2015');

INSERT INTO public.table1 (id, class, r1, r2)
VALUES ('x2', 3, '6/18/2015', '1/25/2015');

INSERT INTO public.table1 (id, class, r1, r2)
VALUES ('x5', 2, '9/3/2015', '1/25/2015');

INSERT INTO public.table1 (id, class, r1, r2)
VALUES ('x3', 1, '9/3/2015', '1/25/2015');

INSERT INTO public.table1 (id, class, r1, r2)
VALUES ('x3', 1, '8/3/2015', '1/25/2015');
```

What I want to do is update column R2 such that for each set of id and class, R2 will be minimum of R1 for that group:

expected_output:

[image]

I am trying to do something like but it's not giving me correct result:

```
UPDATE table1
SET r2 = subquery.p FROM (select id, class, r1, min(r1) OVER (partition by class, id) AS p
FROM table1) AS subquery
```

Could someone please help me with the query?

Thanks

Comment: Please post code and data as text, not images, or better yet, create a fiddle of your data at either https://dbfiddle.uk or https://www.db-fiddle.com. It will make it much easier for other users to answer your question.

Comment: Done. Could you please check again? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably most easily done using an update with join to a CTE of the minimum values:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  select id, class, min(r1) OVER (partition by class, id) AS p
  FROM table1
)
UPDATE table1 t1
SET r2 = CTE.p
FROM CTE
WHERE CTE.id = t1.id AND CTE.class = t1.class
```

Post update with your sample data:

```
id  class   r1          r2
x2  2       01/25/2015  01/25/2015
x2  3       06/28/2015  06/18/2015
x2  3       06/18/2015  06/18/2015
x3  1       09/03/2015  08/03/2015
x3  1       08/03/2015  08/03/2015
x5  2       09/03/2015  09/03/2015
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=381d68c702fb2b12617e79a3b47001c2)